# Calling a custom function in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm fairly new to Scilab, and I'm trying to write a simple function and call it.

How can I write a function in a .sci file in some arbitrary directory and then call it? MATLAB does this automatically. I read a ton of posts talking about using "Execute->Load into scilab" and `getf`, but none of those are present in my version of Scilab (5.3.3). So how in the world can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
exec filelocation\yourFile.sci;
```

should do it